# Chart.js - the rightmost data point cut off for line chart

Tags: layout, charts, linechart

Draw a basic line chart using Chart.js version 2.8.0. 
Observe the rightmost data point is cut off. But the leftmost data point (the first data point) looks intact. 
[image: last data points gets cut off in line chart]

I’ve changed the size of the data point circles by changing values of pointRadius. But even in the smallest value, the data point still gets cut off.

I’m not using any plugin or fancy settings. I am filling the chart are with light gray background colour. But other than that, everything else is a box standard Chart.js.

I’ve recreated the issue here: 
https://codepen.io/LeoU/pen/gVLybO

And here is my options settings.

```
options: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
              var tooltipValue = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
              return "£" + parseInt(tooltipValue).toLocaleString();
          }
      }
      },    
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{ 
                gridLines: {
                  color: "white",
                  lineWidth: 2
                },
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
              min: 0,
              stepSize: 500000,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
              return "£" + value.toLocaleString();
            },
          },
          scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: "Median house price"
        }
              }],
            xAxes: [{
              display: false, 
                ticks: {
                    display: false 
                }
            }]
        }
    },
```

Has anyone seen a similar problem with Chart.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `padding` value to the `right` hand side of the chart. 
I played around with the exact number and 4 looked about right for my chart. But I’d imagine the right number will depend on the size of your `pointRadius` and other variables you have. 
This is what it looks like for me with the changes.

```
options: {
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 4,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0
            }
        }
    }
```

For more about padding for Chart.js, this is their instruction page. 
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html

It is annoying. And, this should be a default setting, really. But this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Adding `padding` on the `layout` just pushes the whole line chart in for me, but the points themselves are still cut off. Here's a GIF: https://cln.sh/EpXrdP

Comment: `offset: true` is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: For me setting `clip` option was the only way to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use offset

```
scales: {
 xAxes: [{
     offset: true
  }]
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you can adjust the amount of padding on the offset?

Comment: Exactly, I would love to use offset, but the space is too big...

Answer (score 1):

As @JunKim mentioned, adding `clip: false` to the options solved the problem for me, after padding not working.

```
options:
   clip: false,
   ...
```